# How to call rest api using wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, rest, api

I want to get list of flights from rest api in wordpress , do anyone has a way so that i could call api from wordpress.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you want to access a REST API URL from your theme?

Comment: Yes, and wanna take data from it to display on wordpress website.

Answer (score 0):

if "flights" is your custom post type you have to add the code below to your `register_post_type` function:

```
'show_in_rest' => true,
```

afterwards you can access the api via:

```
domain.tpl/wp-json/wp/v2/flights
```

if the post type slug is "flights"